# New VGA cable changes the recommended resolution

Tags: windows-10, display, vga

I recently discovered a problem with my desktop-to-monitor VGA cable, so I purchased a new one.

When I re-started my desktop and monitor, the resolution had changed, and the desktop icons were all stuffed to the left of the screen. Checking my display settings, I noted the monitor was now shown as "Generic Non-PnP Monitor."

When I go back to the "original" cable, the display returns to the proper res, and the Screen Resolution page shows the display as Acer X20311, and the resolution as 1600 x 900 (recommended); just as it should be. I have tried 4 (four!) different new cables, and they all do the same thing! The display driver for Radeon X1300/X1550 is up to date.

##### Why does a different monitor cable change the display resolution or how the display is reported?

The only difference in the physical appearance of the VGA cables is the original has little round blocks at each end, filters, I presume... I couldn't find that kind at the Micro Center, but the tech said it shouldn't matter in a quality cable.

Comment: Any fully connected cable should do. Sounds like the cables you tried do not have a (functioning) DDC connection.

Answer (score 2):

PnP means plug and play. When you plug a PnP hardware, it starts working without having to install any driver. When you see a generic Non-PnP monitor on the device manager, it means the Windows was unable to recognize the device.

When this happens, Windows installs a generic monitor driver for it. This does not always work out for the monitor, as the driver could not be functional with the hardware. This leads to monitor issues.

As you already tried using different cables, Faulty or Damaged VGA / Monitor Cable is excluded as a cause of the problem.

Old, outdated, corrupted and/or wrong drivers for your display adapter or graphics card can cause this issue.
Solutions to that problem besides updating Display Card Driver(which you already tried):

1. **Update Generic PnP Monitor Driver**

   1. Right-click on the [*Start menu*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvgNh.png) button and select *Device Manager.*
   2. When the [*Device Manager*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXdjP.png) window opens, expand the *Monitors* option. In the expanded menu of Monitors, right click on *Generic PnP Monitor.* Select the *Update Driver* option from the right-click menu that opens.
   3. After the last step, a [dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iheKb.png) will open up. Here, select the first option, *Search automatically for updated driver software*. This will download and install the driver automatically from the Internet.
   4. When the driver is installed, restart your computer. If Windows was unable to find and install the driver, follow the next step.
   5. Go back to step 3 and this time select [*Browse my computer for driver software*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLcLK.png).
   6. Now, select *[Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo3IV.png)*.
   7. [Mark the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJJH8.png) beside *Show compatible hardware* to view the compatible devices. Here, select the compatible device and then install it.
   8. After installing the driver, restart your computer.
      If the problem still persists, follow the next method.
2. **Uninstall Generic PnP Monitor Driver**

   1. Right-click on the [*Start menu*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvgNh.png) button and select *Device Manager.*
   2. When the [*Device Manager*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG8PG.png) window opens, expand the *Monitors* option. In the expanded menu of Monitors, right click on *Generic PnP Monitor.* Select the *Uninstall device* option from the right-click menu that opens.
   3. When asked for confirmation, select *Uninstall*.
   4. Now, click on [Scan for hardware changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Stvq.png).
      If it didn’t help and you are still facing issues, follow the next method.
3. **Run the [System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026529/windows-10-using-system-file-checker)**
4. **Check for Windows Updates**

Comment: How can i update my generic pnp monitor driver? I check for automatic update and i cant find it.. there are some on the internet but i fear losing my display like monitor going dark for ever and stuff.. Please help me find it.

Comment: @Utkarsh Singh I edited my answer. Hope that will help.

Comment: “When you see a generic PnP monitor on the device manager, it means the Windows was unable to recognize the device.” This is simply, entirely incorrect. But perhaps you meant to write “non-PnP monitor”?

Comment: @BaldEagle I know how to update the drivers the problem is that i cant find a driver to update to. Windows automatic driver search says that its the latest version installed.

Comment: @Utkarsh Singh  
If it says the last version, you don't need to update driver.  Am I correct in assuming that you can't set 1600x900 resolution on your monitor when it is recognized as generic?